# firebase returns undefined user id at one place and the correct value at other

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have the following function to get the user id:

**currentUser.js**

```
import firebase from './firebase';

export default function getCurrentUserID() {
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  var uid; 
  if (user != null) {
    uid = user.uid;  // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use
    // this value to authenticate with your backend server, if
    // you have one. Use User.getToken() instead.
    return uid;
  }
  return uid;
}
```

The following code to enable adding projects using the button, works fine:

**addProject.js**

```
import getCurrentUserID from './currentUserID';
import getFirestoreDB from './firestoreDB';
import Project from './project';
const addProjectBtn = document.getElementById('addProjectBtn');
function addProject() {
    const title = prompt('Insert title');
    const description = prompt('Insert Description');
    const project = new Project(title, description);
    const db = getFirestoreDB();
    const currentUserUID = getCurrentUserID();
    alert(currentUserUID); 
    db.doc(`users/${currentUserUID}/projects/${title}`).set({ ...project }).then(() => {
        alert("Success");
    }).catch((error) => {
        alert("Error " + error);
    });
}

export default function enableAddProjectBtnFunctionality() {
    addProjectBtn.addEventListener('click', addProject);
}
```

But, the following code to display projects, doesn't work. The alert(uid) shows undefined here but shows the correct user id above.

**displayProjects.js**

```
import getCurrentUserID from "./currentUserID";
import getFirestoreDB from './firestoreDB';

var db = getFirestoreDB(); 

export default function displayProjects(){
    var uid = getCurrentUserID(); 
    if(uid){
        alert(uid); 
        var projectsRef = db.collection("users").doc(`${uid}`).collection("projects"); 
        projectsRef.get().then((querySnapshot) => {           
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
                });
            });  
    }
          
}
```

Could someone help me figure out what's the problem here and how I could fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the `displayProjects` method is executed before the user sign-in has been completed.

The proper way to pick up the user state in such scenarios is to use an auth state listener as shown in the first code fragment in the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).

In your code that'd look like this:

```
export default function displayProjects(){
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      var uid = user.uid;
      var projectsRef = db.collection("users").doc(`${uid}`).collection("projects"); 
      projectsRef.get().then((querySnapshot) => {           
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
      });  
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I was just reading an issue simliar to this because of a current problem I'm having with .currentUser: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/462 - is this relevant?

Comment: It's describing the same behavior, and the solution is the same as I showed in my answer: use an auth state listener. Let me know once you've tried the approach from my answer.

Comment: Ahh, I was testing .currentUser as a component loaded, but onAuthStateChanged hadn't caught up.  It seems that .currentUser may be slightly inconsistent.  I'll implement the above instead.  Thanks.

Comment: I called displayProjects() only once, then how does it keep track of the AuthState change?

Comment: When you call `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged`, it registers a permanent listener. Firebase keeps the auth state up to date in the background (refreshing the user's ID token every hour, checking whether the account is still enabled, etc), and calls your listener when there's a chance.